# listview populated from firebase shows blank rows in between list items

Tags: java, android-listview, firebaseui

I am trying to populate data from Firebase realtime database using Firebase list adapter and Firebase list options.I only want specific data from Firebase to be on the my custom listview only if it satisfies a certain condition (in this case diff between dates less than 31). The code below is however giving me blank rows in my listview as show in y attached image, please help why I am getting this and what I can do to stop seeing the blank rows.

[image: output_image]

```
public class CurrentListview extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseListAdapter currentadapter;
    ListView mCurrent;
    String companyname,branchname;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_current_listview);

        mCurrent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.currentreceivableslistview);

        SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("DEVICE_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        companyname = sp.getString("companynam","");
        branchname = sp.getString("branchnam","");

        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("identity").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                .child(companyname+ " debtors accounts").child(branchname);
        query.keepSynced(true);

        FirebaseListOptions<DebtorsAccountsInfo> currentlistoption = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<DebtorsAccountsInfo>()
                .setLayout(R.layout.current_listview_layout_template)
                //.setLifecycleOwner(CurrentListview.this)---replaced with overides 
                .setQuery(query,DebtorsAccountsInfo.class)
                .build();

        currentadapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(currentlistoption) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull Object model, int position) {
                try{
                    Date date1,date2;
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    String datetoday = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendar.getTime());
                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    datetoday = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

                    //setting dates
                    date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(datetoday);
                    DebtorsAccountsInfo currentdebtor = (DebtorsAccountsInfo) model;
                    String disbursementdate= currentdebtor.getDisbursementdate();
                    date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(disbursementdate);

                    //Comparing dates
                    long difference = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) ;
                    long differenceinDates = difference/(24*60*60*1000);

                    if(differenceinDates<31  && differenceinDates>0){
                        try {
                            TextView mClientname= v.findViewById(R.id.current_client_name_lstvw_item);
                            //TextView mPaidamount = v.findViewById(R.id.paid_amount_lstvw_item);
                            //TextView mDuedate = v.findViewById(R.id.due_date_lstvw_item);
                            TextView mBalance = v.findViewById(R.id.current_balance_lstvw_item);
                            //TextView mDisbursementdate = v.findViewById(R.id.disbursement_date_lstvw_item);
                            mClientname.setText(currentdebtor.getName().toString());
                            mBalance.setText(currentdebtor.getAmountdue().toString());
                        }
                        catch (Exception e){}
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                }
            }
        };
        mCurrent.setAdapter(currentadapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        currentadapter.startListening();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        currentadapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```